# MySQL: SUM() on Self-Joined table

Tags: mysql, sum, self-join

I have the following table named `Stock_Level`. (It has around 200,000 rows)

```
| sku | location_id | stock_level | allocated | on_order | date_booked_in      | date_last_sold      | date_last_stock_take| status_since        |
|-----|-------------|-------------|-----------|----------|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
| 1   | 1           | 100         | 2         | 15       | 2020-12-01 12:34:00 | 2020-11-25 12:34:00 | 2021-01-01 12:00:00 | 2021-02-09 12:55:00 |
| 2   | 1           | 50          | 1         | 0        | 2020-11-02 12:34:00 | 2020-10-09 12:34:00 | 2021-01-01 12:00:00 | 2021-02-09 12:55:00 |
| 3   | 1           | 10          | 0         | 12       | 2020-08-05 12:34:00 | 2020-05-04 12:34:00 | 2021-01-01 12:00:00 | 2021-02-09 12:55:00 |
| 1   | 2           | 80          | 0         | 13       | 2020-09-09 12:34:00 | 2020-12-06 12:34:00 | 2021-01-03 12:00:00 | 2021-02-09 13:55:00 |
| 2   | 2           | 35          | 3         | 0        | 2020-07-10 12:34:00 | 2020-08-05 12:34:00 | 2021-01-03 12:00:00 | 2021-02-09 12:55:00 |
| 1   | 3           | 60          | 1         | 0        | 2020-08-12 12:34:00 | 2020-09-04 12:34:00 | 2021-02-03 12:00:00 | 2021-02-09 12:55:00 |
| 2   | 3           | 9           | 0         | 17       | 2020-05-30 12:34:00 | 2020-01-01 12:34:00 | 2021-02-03 12:00:00 | 2021-02-09 12:55:00 |
```

PRIMARY key is on `sku` and `location_id`
There is also an INDEX on `status_since`

A SKU can be in multiple locations. When an item is booked in, sold or stock taken, `status_since` is updated to `NOW()`

**What I'm trying to do**

I have a script that runs every 15 minutes, selecting items that have been updated in the last 15 minutes, with the SUM of (stock_level - allocated) for that sku, along with the total number on order and the `MAX()` values of `date_booked_in`, `date_last_sold` and `date_last_stock_take`

The code that I've currently got is this:

```
SELECT sku,
    SUM(stock_level - allocated) AS available,
    SUM(on_order) AS on_order,
    MAX(date_booked_in) AS date_booked_in,
    MAX(date_last_sold) AS date_last_sold,
    MAX(date_last_stock) AS date_last_stock
FROM Stock_Level
WHERE
    sku IN(
        SELECT sku
        FROM Stock_Level
        WHERE
            status_since>= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
            AND status_since<= NOW()
    )
GROUP BY sku
```

This works fine when there are only a few items that have been recently updated; however sometimes many hundreds can be updated within a 15 minute period, and this query grinds to a halt.

I suspect there is a way to do this with a self join rather than using an IN() clause but I can't for the life of me work it out.

What would be some potential ways to rewrite this query?

Comment: I don't think you need a sub query or self join at all..just test WHERE
            status_since>= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
            AND status_since<= NOW()

Comment: As @P.Salmon said, it makes no sense to use a subquery, you can just use WHERE and it will be faster

Comment: @P.Salmon If I don't use a subquery, I only get the row that was last updated. So, using the data in the table above as an example, assuming that the query is run at 14:00, the data returned would be:

available 80

when in fact is should be

available 240 (the total stock for SKU 1)

The subquery I've got returns the correct data but is very slow.

Comment: OK so you reach back forever for any sku transacted in the specified period..

Comment: @P.Salmon Not sure what you mean?

Comment: Replacing an in, join or exists by one of the others is a faq.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` which is much faster than `IN` and is always recommended:

```
SELECT sku,
    SUM(stock_level - allocated) AS available,
    SUM(on_order) AS on_order,
    MAX(date_booked_in) AS date_booked_in,
    MAX(date_last_sold) AS date_last_sold,
    MAX(date_last_stock) AS date_last_stock
FROM Stock_Level
WHERE
    EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM Stock_Level sl2
        WHERE
            sl2.status_since>= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
            AND sl2.status_since<= NOW()
            AND sku.sku = sl2.sku 
    )
GROUP BY sku
```